# Android Test project - receiving events from activity being tested?

Tags: android, junit, android-testing

Is it possible to receive events withing the android project generated from the main activity?

So i can test events?

Is this the best way of testing events?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Activity Testing Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html) how to test activities in Android.
To test activity's events [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) class is used.
[TouchUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html) class is useful to generate touch events.